# How to enable Office 365 to work as Identity Provider

Tags: microsoft-office-365, single-sign-on

I'm trying to set up my application to use Office 365 as Identity Provider for Single Sign On but I can't find specific instructions to do so.

Comment: This question is way too vague to answer. SSO for what? From where? For who?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not going to use "Office 365" as your identity provider: you need to look at Azure Active Directory, which is the identity provider behind all Microsoft cloud services (including Office 365).

That said, the specifics heavily depend on *where* you want to perform SSO (i.e., which application/service/system); here are some random examples:

https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=95955.htm
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/federatingADFSazure.htm
https://www.ge.com/digital/documentation/apm-classic/t_apm_sso_configure_azure_ad_as_idp.html

Basically, it all boils down to setting up a SAML federation; but, as I said, the specific steps vary with each application.